# Persistent "503 UnknownError" when syncing messages in specific mailFolders (via deltas)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

While syncing messages via the [mailFolder delta endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), specific mailFolders will provide `@odata.deltaLink`s that when requested return 503 errors.

This affects 4 of roughly 6500 mailFolders that we are currently syncing. Each of these 4 is in a different Office 365 tenant, and includes both default (e.g. "Sent Items") and custom folders.

- `@odata.nextLink` works correctly. The mailFolder receiving new messages also doesn't fix the issue:

  - If the syncing progress is restarted, that is, throwing away the existing `@odata.deltaLink`, following the `@odata.nextLink` chain will correctly return all messages (including ones created after the deltaLink was provided). However, the newly provided `@odata.deltaLink`, while different, will also return the error.
- This issue affects both the 1.0 and beta versions of this endpoint.
- All other mailFolders for the affected users work correctly.
- This issue has existed from the very first time we've attempted to sync affected mailFolders. The first time that *we* saw it was 2019-08-03 08:38 PM UTC, though the issue has likely existed longer than this.
- The response does *not* include a [Retry-After header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors).
- All of our other 6500 mailFolders have correctly functioning message deltas, and we're able to correctly sync them with our code.

Can be reproduced via Curl to an affected message delta URL.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" "$delta_url"`

A sample of one of the specific error codes returned, with a real request id:

Request to:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/<mailFolderId>/messages/delta?$skiptoken=<skipToken>`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "Error while processing response.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a4441195-f469-47c8-bea3-cdeedef2e396",
      "date": "2019-08-08T21:24:20"
    }
  }
}
```

This other potentially relevant header was on the response:

```
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_7","ADSiteName":"WUS"}}
```

Comment: are you still experiencing the issue? could you provide new request ids please?